# android and node.js

Tags: android, json, node.js, client-side

Im trying to connect to a nodejs server through my android client but i cant even make the connection.. I tried to follow some tutorials but in vain.. How can i send a json object to the nodejs server..

```
try{
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    URI uri = new URI("http://192.168.1.100:8080/"); 
    request.setURI(uri);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    Log.i("request", "OBject made");
    json.put("users", et.getText().toString());
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
    Log.i("request", "String Entity made");
    se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
    request.setEntity(se);
    Log.i("request", "Set String Entity made");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    tv.setText(response.getEntity().getContent().toString());

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any error message?

Comment: Try to access that URI via cURL. Does that work? What do you get back?

Comment: Well sir I didnt tried via cURL since i'm new to android so i have no idea how to connect it.. Its a simple nodejs server within my network. Onw of my friend created it. But i can't send anything via the above code, what is most discouraging that i can't connect it..

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

1. Are you trying this from your office computer? Can that computer connect to `http://192.168.1.100:8080/`? (*try it in cURL or via a web-browser*)
2. Are you trying this from your android device? Is that device on the correct network?
3. Does the exception tell you the problem?

If #1 or #2 fail, then the issue is a configuration issue. Otherwise, I would at least include the error message.

Comment: Thanks sir.. it is accessible by web browser. I'm not trying it from an office computer neither from an android device. I have nodejs server on one computer and android demo client on the other, within a network at my home.

Comment: Sir  it does not shows any exception. The demo app executes correctly but it does not leave the emulator.. just gets the response.getEntity() == EOFStreamInput.. I really need to make the connection..